# Optional Chaining in JavaScript returns undefined instead of null when the variable to be tested is null

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

So, I am reading optional chaining in JavaScript and a question popped into my head.

Consider the code below:

```js
let person = null
let street = person?.street // returns undefined
```

My question is that, if the variable `person` is `null` to begin with, then why is doing optional chaining result to setting the variable as `undefined` and not `null`?

If the person was `undefined`, then I guess, for me, setting it to `undefined` is reasonable because the variable is of course `undefined`, like the below:

```js
let person
let street = person?.street // returns undefined
```

PS: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'll delete it if someone agrees. :)

PPS: If this question is duplicated, pls drop the link and I'll give it a go. Thank you, very much.

Comment: Does the [first paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) answer your question?

Comment: @Palladium02 I kinda get that it is similar to street = (person == null || person == undefined) ? undefined : person.name. I'm kind of confused as to why undefined is explicitly returned and not the person (to get null or undefined depending on the nature of the person variable)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An optional chain does not evaluate to the nullish value on which the property was accessed, but to `undefined` - just like you get `undefined` when a property does not exist in an object.

Conceptually, think of `person?.street` not as

```
person && person.street
```

but rather as

```
(person ?? {}).street
```

Though accurately (especially when chained further, since it does short-circuit instead of evaluating the rest of the chain) it's really

```
person != null ? person.street : undefined
```

---

See also the [FAQ on the *optional chaining* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining#faq):

> **Why does `(null)?.b` evaluate to `undefined` rather than `null`?**
>
> Neither `a.b` nor `a?.b` is intended to preserve arbitrary information
> on the base object `a`, but only to give information about the
> property `"b"` of that object. If a property `"b"` is absent from `a`,
> this is reflected by `a.b === undefined` and `a?.b === undefined`.
>
> In particular, the value `null` is considered to have no properties;
> therefore, `(null)?.b` is `undefined`.

Comment: `If a property "b" is absent from a, this is reflected by a.b === undefined and a?.b === undefined. ` I see. That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can always fallback to null using the logical OR operator `||`

```js
const person = null
let street = person?.street || null
console.log(street)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the manual about [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

> The ?. operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is **`nullish`** (***`null`*** or ***`undefined`***), the expression ***short-circuits*** with a return value of ***`undefined`***. When used with function calls, it returns ***undefined*** if the given function does not exist.

Comment: I kinda get that it is similar to `street = (person == null || person == undefined) ? undefined : person.name`. I'm kind of confused as to why `undefined` is explicitly returned and not the `person` (to get null or undefined depending on the nature of the person variable).

Comment: To keep the return value consistent when the variable has `nullish` values. If we needed to return either `null` or `undefined` or the value of `person` - then, we may as well use `person` directly, no?

Comment: @jsN00b, oh yeah, point taken. My little brain said "If the variable was null to begin with, then why make it undefined during an optional chaining?".

Comment: @Hansel you can imagine it (to a certain extent) like it's just softening the rules in such a way that `null.anything` and `undefined.anything` are `undefined` (instead of crashing) much like `({}).anything` is `undefined` as well (plus `null()` and `undefined()` would then also return `undefined`).

Answer (score 0):

The reason the result is `undefined` and not `null` is because of optional chaining (`?.`).

---

If optional chaining wasn't available, your code would've resulted in an error, saying that `null` has no properties.

```js
const person = null;
person.street // ERROR!
```

But, since you have optional chaining, it only results in `undefined`.

```js
const person = null;
person?.street // undefined
```

---

This is why optional chaining results in `undefined` (if the value is `null` or `undefined`); to avoid throwing an error!

Hope this answered your question!